# New Zealand daylight saving time broken in Chrome 71

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Just updated to Chrome 71.

Chrome 71 returns `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` as -720 which is missing the hour for daylight savings.

Chrome 70 returned `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` correctly as -780.

I'm in New Zealand and we should have 1 hour added for daylight savings. No such problem in other browsers.

[image]

Can someone from Chrome team fix please?

Comment: This is the correct place to file this bug: http://crbug.com

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem: Using Berlin timezone `new Date(1554069600000).getTimezoneOffset()` is -120 on Mac and Linux but -60 on Windows 7 on Chrome 71. Firefox returns -120 on Windows 7 which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been fixed now. If you have this issue, update your Chrome.